# How to insert string as ISODate to mongo db, using golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have the following transaction struct

```
type Transaction struct {
    ID       primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Category primitive.ObjectID `bson:"category,omitempty"`
    Amount   string             `json:"amount" binding:"required"`
    Owner    primitive.ObjectID `bson:"owner,omitempty"`
    Date     primitive.DateTime `bson:"date" json:"date"`
    //Date     time.Time          `bson:"date" json:"date"`
}
var transaction models.Transaction
if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&transaction); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    return
}
createdTransaction, createErr := handler.collection.InsertOne(handler.ctx, transaction)
```

I am trying to pass the date, in the following format `Mon Jan 30 2023 17:27:16 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`, and I get the Bad Request error.
How can I insert the following date format as `ISODate` into mongodb?

Comment: Use `time.Time` in your struct. Parse the time if it's available as a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```golang
createdTransaction, createErr := handler.collection.InsertOne(handler.ctx, transaction)
```

To include `&transaction` like this as the final parameter `InsertOne` takes a reference to the data to be stored, not a value:

```golang
createdTransaction, createErr := handler.collection.InsertOne(handler.ctx, &transaction)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Transaction struct {
    ID       primitive.ObjectID       `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Category primitive.ObjectID       `bson:"category,omitempty" json:"category"`
    Amount   string                   `json:"amount" binding:"required"`
    Owner    primitive.ObjectID       `bson:"owner,omitempty" json:"owner"`
    InvDt    primitive.DateTime       `bson:"invdt,omitempty" json:"invdt,omitempty"`
    Date     string                   `json:"date" binding:"required"`
    Cat      []map[string]interface{} `json:"cat" bson:"cat"`
}
const shortForm = "2006-01-02"
dt, _ := time.Parse(shortForm, transaction.Date)
transaction.InvDt = primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(dt)
```

As was mentioned before, i need to use parse time as string